# Drop table if exists in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop table if it is exists in the present working database of PostgreSQL. For which I am trying the following query.

**Example**:

```
var1 := 'IF EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE name = ''Table_'|| Suffix ||''') then
      DROP TABLE Table_'||Suffix||'';

execute var1;
```

But getting error near `IF`.

Comment: Please add more context to your code, please post the full statement you trying to execute.

Comment: What's wrong with `drop table if exists`?

Comment: Show the **exact text** of the error message, and the surrounding code. Also, what's the PostgreSQL version? `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`execute` executes SQL statements, not PL/pgSQL commands. The IF statement is a PL/pgSQL construct.

In any case you can use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...
```

(see [the manual page for DROP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html)).